SwiftUI Charts how to avoid automatically groups accessibility elements on the graph
I have a BarMark Chart and I am using .accessibilityLabel and .accessibilityValue to customize the accessibility Text for each bar. With small number of bar on the graph, this logic works fine, but when there are more bar, they automatically groups and mess-up the accessibility Text. I wonder if there is anyway to avoid this automatic grouping
This is my code
    var body: some View {
        let salesData: [(Date, Double)] = [
                (Date().addingTimeInterval(-1 * 24 * 60 * 60), 120),
                (Date().addingTimeInterval(-2 * 24 * 60 * 60), 150),
                (Date().addingTimeInterval(-3 * 24 * 60 * 60), 100),
                (Date().addingTimeInterval(-4 * 24 * 60 * 60), 50),
                (Date().addingTimeInterval(-5 * 24 * 60 * 60), 150),
                (Date().addingTimeInterval(-6 * 24 * 60 * 60), 140),
                (Date().addingTimeInterval(-7 * 24 * 60 * 60), 130),
                (Date().addingTimeInterval(-8 * 24 * 60 * 60), 180),
                (Date().addingTimeInterval(-9 * 24 * 60 * 60), 50),
                (Date().addingTimeInterval(-10 * 24 * 60 * 60), 80),
                (Date().addingTimeInterval(-11 * 24 * 60 * 60), 80),
                (Date().addingTimeInterval(-12 * 24 * 60 * 60), 100),
                (Date().addingTimeInterval(-13 * 24 * 60 * 60), 150),
                (Date().addingTimeInterval(-14 * 24 * 60 * 60), 150),
                (Date().addingTimeInterval(-15 * 24 * 60 * 60), 90),
            ]

                Chart {
                    ForEach(salesData, id: \.0) {  date, sales in
                        BarMark(
                          x: .value("Day", date),
                          y: .value("Amount", sales)
                        ).accessibilityLabel(date.formatted(date: .abbreviated, time: .omitted))
                            .accessibilityValue("Amount: \(sales.formatted(.currency(code: "USD")))")
                      }
                }
                .accessibilityElement(children: .contain)
                .frame(height: 300)
    }

When running accessibility, it groups 2 columns into one element automatically

I am not sure if any setting to avoid this auto grouping, I need the behavior like the activity chart on the Health-app


Your code seems to work fine with 12 or less days of data. Maybe consider designing the chart for a week or the previous 10 days.

unfortunately, my requirement is showing a whole month of data

@HuyVu having the same problem

The grouping appears to work fine by formatting the x values as strings rather than leaving the x values as dates:
x: .value("Day", date.formatted(date: .abbreviated , time: .omitted)),

Then a single day can be selected:

Making that one change did cause other changes that you may want to adjust. Because the x values are strings, the displayed order is the array order rather than date order.
Label fix: Every day's date is now displayed along the x axis. The following is a fix for those compressed labels, to be added to Chart:
.chartXAxis(content: {
    AxisMarks { value in
        AxisValueLabel (orientation: .vertical) {
            if let displayValue = value.as(String.self) {
                Text(displayValue)
            }
        }
    }
})



Thank you a lot, @Marcy! This is exactly what I needed
